# Connect to a second computer at startup

Tags: macos

First, I'm sure this question has an answer somewhere, but I cannot find it.

Is there a way for my main computer to connect to a backup computer on startup? I want to run TimeMachine from the remote machine. The connection would be over the network.

Comment: Connect how? Remote desktop? File access/sharing? What OS is the 'back up' computer?

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not fully understanding.

Computer 1 connects to Computer 2 over the network. Computer 2 acts as a back up disk for computer 1, so C1 can run TimeMachine, using C2 as storage? Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, your scenario is exactly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mac shared as a Time Machine backup destination**

On the 'host/storage/backup' Mac

1. Go to System Prefs > Sharing
2. Enable File Sharing
3. Add a folder as the back up destination (note, you might want to partition a section of the HD for this) under "Shared Folders"
4. Right click, Advanced Options
5. Select "Share as Time Machine backup destination"

Then on the 'working' Mac, as long as both devices are visible to each other on the network, you should see the 'backup' Mac as a TimeMachine destination.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202784#mac